# How to find vanished medium-sized spider?

Tags: home, pest-control

So, we had unwanted visit of a spider yesterday. It seems to be a non-adult version of a [Tegenaria domestica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegenaria_domestica) or similar (trigger warning: pictures in the article). The size was about 3-4cm in diameter, including legs. To my knowledge, it doesn’t do a lot of webs and it is rather fast moving. It needs to go because one of us is suffering from arachnophobia, and ideally it goes in a controlled way and not by re-appearing out of nowhere and grown up or in a bad moment.

The spider was seen vanishing behind a cardboard box. Then it was left unattended for a while (which was arguably not smart, but yeah). The cardboard box was investigated later and the spider couldn’t be found there or in nearby corners. So it has vanished *somewhere* in the kitchen (or possibly even other rooms), which is a bad situation to be in.

So we tried to set up a "trap" by making an extra-dark corner close to the window, which hasn’t yielded any success yet. Since it’s the kitchen, there are quite a few appliances which we can’t even move. Ideally, there would be a way to force it out of potential hiding places and into some kind of trap (or even a well-reachable corner).

We would like to avoid having to call in pest control for various reasons, so a life hack is needed!

Comment: Ironically, the only cure for arachnophobia is exposure to spiders.

Answer (score 1):

[Sticky fly-paper](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075PVTPZ4) is safe and effective. You might try leaving tape sticky-side up, though it might not be "soft" enough to trap a spider.

That said, these spiders are considered harmless (though *startlingly* large) and are beneficial in that they eat insects in the house. When I've found them inside, they are easily captured in a glass or plastic container and set free outside.